# Keras Model With CuDNNLSTM Layers Doesn't Work on Production Server

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I have used an AWS p3 instance to train the following model using GPU acceleration:

```
x = CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

After training I saved the model with Keras' `save_model` function and moved it to a separate production server that doesn't have a GPU.

When I attempt to predict using the model on the production server it fails with the following error:

> No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

I'm guessing this is because the production server doesn't have GPU support, but I was hoping this wouldn't be a problem. Is there any way I can use this model on a production server without a GPU?

Comment: You can still use `CuDNNLSTM` layers for training, but on your prediction server, they have to be replaced with `LSTM`. You can try to use `save_weights` (instead of `save_model`) on the GPU machine and `load_weights` on the CPU machine.

Comment: There seems no work around, @Yu-Yang's solution works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't, CuDNN requires the use of a CUDA GPU. You have to replace your CuDNNLSTM layers with standard LSTM ones.

Comment: Replacing CuDNNLSTM layers with LSTM layers won't give the right results because the format is different.

Comment: Yes, you can. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758489/4913143)

Answer (score 4):

**short answer:**
Yes, you can.

Just need to re create your architecture with LSTM layer instead of CuDNNLSTM.

Your code should be the following:

```py
x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

and then

```py
model.load_weights(path_to_your_weights_file)
```

Notice the `recurrent_activation='sigmoid'`. This is very important.

**Long explanation:**

LSTM and CuDNNLSTM are compatible eacth other, so you can load the weigths from one to another with no problem. However, their default values for the activation function are slightly different. Some times it leads to small differences between one and the other, but it may lead to very big ones, as reported [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9463).

> [The activation values] for CuDNNLSTM [...] are hard-coded in CuDNN and cannot be changed from Keras. They correspond to activation='tanh' and recurrent_activation='sigmoid' (slightly different than default hard_sigmoid in [LSTM] Keras). [ref](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8860#issuecomment-358627597)

Comment: amazing method. load weights from gpu model to a cpu empty model, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this would be to
   **Replace the CuDNN layers with regular keras layer,
   ie. convert CudNNLSTM to LSTM ,etc**

 If using Google Colab go to Runtime>Change Runtime Settings and set the accelerator to **GPU**

Answer (score 0):

You definitely **can** train on CuDNNLSTM, then run inference on LSTM.

The trick is to change your layer architecture from CuDNNLSTM to LSTM in your .json file, before loading your h5 file. The 2x bias in the CuDNNLSTM weights will automatically convert when you load your h5 file, but Keras **won't** automatically change your .json file for you.

In other words, just open up your saved .json model, change all instances of CuDNNLSTM to LSTM, save the .json file, then load your .h5 file. You should then be able to run inference with the model.

Comment: need to change also the `reccurrent_activation` checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758489/4913143)

Answer (score -2):

try

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue. without GPU it will be still the same. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758489/4913143)