# Tensorflow: Use model trained in CUDNNLSTM in cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a model using CUDNNLSTM in tensorflow using GPU. When I try to use the model in cpu for inferencing, I am getting this error:

```
Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[Node: cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNN = CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direction="bidirectional", dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input", is_training=false, rnn_mode="lstm", seed=87654321, seed2=4567](Reshape_1, cudnn_lstm/zeros, cudnn_lstm/zeros_1, cudnn_lstm/opaque_kernel/read)]]
```

So, how can we use this model in cpu?

Comment: It looks like you need to run CUDNN on the GPU. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086014/keras-model-with-cudnnlstm-layers-doesnt-work-on-production-server 

Possibly you could just save the weights from the trained model and then read those in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras Model With CuDNNLSTM Layers Doesn't Work on Production Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086014/keras-model-with-cudnnlstm-layers-doesnt-work-on-production-server)

Answer (score 5):

Please have a look at the comments in tensorflow source code of the CuDNN LSTM layer at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py

They have described how to do, what you want, from line 83 onwards. Basically, after using CuDNN layers for training, you need to transfer weights to a model made with CuDNN Compatible LSTM Cells. Such a model will run on both CPU and GPU. Also, as far as I know, CuDNN LSTM layers in tensorflow are time major so don't forget to transpose your inputs (I'm not sure about this in the latest tensorflow version, please confirm this).

For a short complete example based on above, checkout melgor's gist:

https://gist.github.com/melgor/41e7d9367410b71dfddc33db34cba85f?short_path=29ebfc6

Comment: Do you know how to do it using Keras layers?

Comment: Please have a look at this discussion of @Yu-Yang and fchollet 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/8307

It seems that there was indeed an issue and the appropriate changes have been merged to latest keras branch. If after updating keras, it still does not work for you, you can do one of 2 things.
1. Copy the changes (highlighted in the PR above) to your local Keras files.
OR
2. Get the entire updated Keras repo from the same link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @OP Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Antimony, I am sorry about that and maybe I would try to check ur code. But I request you to please make it clear to any viewers of the answer that your problem was related to keras and not what the OP asked. OP asked how to do it in tensorflow and I know it works and this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Reason: tensorflow doesn`t see your GPU
```

### Fix: install CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN SDK (compatible with your tf version), run: 'pip uninstall tensorflow'; 'pip install tensorflow-gpu'

```
Summary:
    1. check if tensorflow sees your GPU (optional)
    2. check if your videocard can work with tensorflow (optional)
    3. find versions of CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN SDK, compatible with your tf version
        (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux)
    4. install CUDA Toolkit
        (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)
    5. install cuDNN SDK 
        (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)
    6. pip uninstall tensorflow; pip install tensorflow-gpu 
    7. check if tensorflow sees your GPU
    * source - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu


Detailed instruction:
    1. check if tensorflow sees your GPU (optional)
        from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
        def get_available_devices():
            local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
            return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]
        print(get_available_devices()) 
        # my output was => ['/device:CPU:0']
        # good output must be => ['/device:CPU:0', '/device:GPU:0']
    2. check if your card can work with tensorflow (optional)
        * my PC: GeForce GTX 1060 notebook (driver version - 419.35), windows 10, jupyter notebook
        * tensorflow needs Compute Capability 3.5 or higher. (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements)
        - https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus
        - select "CUDA-Enabled GeForce Products"
        - result - "GeForce GTX 1060    Compute Capability = 6.1"
        - my card can work with tf!
    3. find versions of CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN SDK, that you need
        a) find your tf version
            import tensorflow as tf
            print(tf.__version__)
            # my output was => 1.13.1
        b) find right versions of CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN SDK for your tf version
            https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux
            * it is written for linux, but worked in my case
            see, that tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1 needs: CUDA Toolkit v10.0, cuDNN SDK v7.4
    4. install CUDA Toolkit
        a) install CUDA Toolkit 10.0
            https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive
            select: CUDA Toolkit 10.0 and download base installer (2 GB)
            installation settings: select only CUDA
                (my installation path was: D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\Cuda_v_10_0\Development)
        b) add environment variables:
            system variables / path must have:
                D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\Cuda_v_10_0\Development\bin
                D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\Cuda_v_10_0\Development\libnvvp
                D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\Cuda_v_10_0\Development\extras\CUPTI\libx64
                D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\Cuda_v_10_0\Development\include
    5. install cuDNN SDK
        a) download cuDNN SDK v7.4
            https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive (needs registration, but it is simple)
            select "Download cuDNN v7.4.2 (Dec 14, 2018), for CUDA 10.0"
        b) add path to 'bin' folder into "environment variables / system variables / path":
            D:\Programs\x64\Nvidia\cudnn_for_cuda_10_0\bin
    6.  pip uninstall tensorflow
        pip install tensorflow-gpu 
    7. check if tensorflow sees your GPU
        restart your PC
        print(get_available_devices()) 
        # now this code should return => ['/device:CPU:0', '/device:GPU:0']
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is your JSON file, which has your model architecture, is still configured for CuDNNLSTM. Keras can now automatically load CuDNNLSTM weights into an LSTM architecture, but it won't automatically change the architecture for you.

The fix for this is simple: open your .json file, and change every instance of `CuDNNLSTM` to `LSTM`. Save the JSON file, then you should be able to load the weights from your .h5 file.